# shell script to return value

Tags: awk

I have below shell script which produce output as desired.

```
RuleNum=$1    

cat input.txt |awk -v var=$RuleNum '$1==var {out=$1; for(i=NF;i >=0;i--)if($i~/bps/){sub("bps","",$i);out=out" "$i} print out;out=""}' 

./downup.sh 20
20 BW-IN:2560000 BW-OUT:2048000
```

i want output as below

```
./downup.sh 20    
256000 2048000
./downup.sh 36
2560000 2048000
```

below is the `input.txt`

```
20 name:abc addr:203.45.247.247/255.255.255.255 WDW-THRESH:12 BW-OUT:10000000bps BW-IN:15000000bps STATSDEVICE:test247 STATS:Enabled (4447794/0) <IN OUT>
25 name:xyz160 addr:203.45.233.160/255.255.255.224 STATSDEVICE:test160 STATS:Enabled priority:pass-thru (1223803328/0) <IN OUT>
37 name:testgrp2 <B> WDW-THRESH:8 BW-BOTH:192000bps STATSDEVICE:econetgrp2 STATS:Enabled (0/0) <Group> START:NNNNNNN-255-0 STOP:NNNNNNN-255-0
62 name:blahblahl54 addr:203.45.225.54/255.255.255.255 WDW-THRESH:5 BWLINK:cbb256 BW-BOTH:256000bps STATSDEVICE:hellol54 STATS:Enabled (346918/77) <IN OUT>
```

Comment: Time to start learning how to use the [markdown editor](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) instead of relying on others to make your posts readable.

Answer (score 0):

Add `sub("BW.*:", "", $i)` after the existing `sub()`.

And `cat` isn't necessary. Just put the filename at the end of the line:

```
awk ... input.txt
```

To eliminate the rule number from the output, remove `out = $1;`.

Here is the result with an addition to avoid printing a space at the beginning of each line:

```
awk -v var=$RuleNum '$1==var {for(i = NF; i >= 0; i--) if ($i ~ /bps/) {sub("bps","",$i); sub("BW.*:", "", $i); out = out delim $i; delim = OFS} print out; out = delim = ""}'
```

Comment: @Levon: I don't understand what you mean regarding the command line argument.

Comment: @Levon: That's simply a matter of removing `out = $1;`. I missed that requirement. I'll add this to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @rajiv If this solves your problem you should [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. It'll reward you and the poster with some rep points and mark this problem as solved.